# Neo4j relationship direction

Tags: relationship, neo4j, graph-databases

I have a collection of users. I am connecting them to the root node of the graph via a relationship.

Should I make the relationship point from the root node to the user or should I make it point from the user to the root node.

What are the benefits and drawbacks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Neo4j, there is not differences about features or performances depending on the relationship direction. So the best practice is to make your choice based on the how it sounds the best.

Here for exemple, I would create a relationship from the root node to the user, as the root node is a kind of "owner", and I want to traverse *from* the root *to* the users if I want them all.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to use Spring Data Neo4j (SDN), make a connection from the user to the (sub-)reference node, because SDN loads all relationships from the source to the target when adding a new target node. If you have a lot of users, all those existing relationships will be loaded when adding a new one.

Otherwise the direction of a relationship is just a matter of taste as cporte already mentioned.

Comment: Thanks James, I'm not using it at the moment but that is good to be aware of for future proofing the application.

Comment: @james Hi James, I'm interesting on your answer, for a real case, e.g. (Company) -[:EMPLOY] - (Person), so as your answer, the `Person` should keep the reference? right? so how about the `Company` entity?